# How can I pivot my data into a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a deployment table that I track which version of code is deployed to each environment. It looks something like this:

| Application_Name | Environment | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Biztalk | QA1 | 1.0.0.1 |
| Biztalk | QA1 | 1.0.0.2 |
| Biztalk | QA2 | 1.0.0.2 |
| BPM | QA1 | 1.0.0.1 |
| BPM | QA2 | 1.0.0.2 |
| Websphere | QA1 | 1.0.0.1 |
| Websphere | QA2 | 1.0.0.2 |

I can easily export all of my QA1 results into an excel sheet and then my QA2 results in a different sheet and then vlookup to pull the values in, and then do an exact to see if they match but that's not very efficient. There has to be a way to directly query this, to get something like this:

| Application_Name | QA1 | QA2 | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biztalk | 1.0.0.2 | 1.0.0.2 | 1 |
| BPM | 1.0.0.1 | 1.0.0.2 | 0 |
| Websphere | 1.0.0.1 | 1.0.0.2 | 0 |

Part of the trick is that this table contains a decade worth of deployments, so I need to only pull the latest of each. I figured I could just order by the deployed_date column in descending order (but I don't need to display it). Anyway, I got something like this, but it's definitely not working.

```
select top 500
FROM
(
    SELECT       [application_name]
      ,[environment]
      ,[version]
      ,[deployed_date]
    FROM [Deployment_History]
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(AVG([Submitted]) FOR [Environment] IN([QA1],[QA2])) AS PivotTable;
```

Any help would be appreciated to let me know if I'm barking down the right tree or not.

Comment: The syntax of your SQL statement probably identifies the RDBMS you're using but it's customary to do so explicitly by adding an additional tag to your post.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm rather lost.  BizTalk is deployed twice.  How is that handled?  Your query refers to `Submitted` but it is not defined.  What is the logic for the last column?  It is not clear.  The results for Websphere are not consistent with the source data.

Comment: It's a history of deployments. Version1 was deployed on some date, and later version 2 came along and was deployed over top of it.

Answer (score 0):

use following query

```
select *,case when QA1 = QA2 then 1 else 0 end as match
from
(
  select *
  from Deployment_History
) as SourceTable  
pivot
(
   max(Version) for Environment in(QA1,QA2)
) as PivotTable
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e969e6e057cbf176b8dd8f1b0ba91e5d)